# Can I query the Unicode version of an Android device programatically?

Tags: android, unicode, version, icu

I know I can check the Android Release number and some related info via `android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE` and I can check the ICU (Internationalization Components for Unicode) version via `android.icu.util.VersionInfo.ICU_VERSION` but I can't seem to find a way to check the Unicode version itself.

So far the best I can find is [a table relating the versions of various system components](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization#versioning-nougat) in the Android internationalization documentation, and it's not quite up-to-date:

```
Platform (API level)                    ICU     CLDR    Unicode
---------------------------------------------------------------
Android 7.0 - 7.1 (API levels 24 - 25)  56      28      8.0
Android 8.0 - 8.1 (API levels 26 - 27)  58.2    30.0.3  9.0
Android 9 (API level 28)                60.2    32.0.1  10.0
Android 10 (API level 29)               63.2    34      11.0
Android 11 (API level 30)               66.1    36      13.0
Android 12 (API level 31)               68.2    38.1    13.0
```

My year-old cheap Chinese phone is Android 13 with ICU 70.1, which isn't in the table and isn't the latest version, which is also missing from that table.

Is there a deterministic way for my app to get the Unicode version info from the system? Or do I just have to find more up-to-date tables and put them in my code?

(As a bonus question it would be nice if I can also check the CLDR version programmatically.)

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character#getName(int) and test characters which are included only on "later" versions. Unfortunately this method doesn't work for *future*.